Program returned error: "Overlapping copy"
I tried to mint NFT to someone , but it gives me a error "Error: Raw transaction 5A6sSQPmAUBTQXDkrz9DM1tkYnwp7mjFLLi2S2cUpVjxnkYXHaSvHLHq2fz7Z5ViDdghrAgKPwqBVDC5m7ud3oEK failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,"ProgramFailedToComplete"]}})",
here is my program code
pub fn buytokens(
    ctx: Context<BuyTokens>,
    amount: u64
) -> Result<()>{
    let bta = &ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account;
    let bta_balance = &bta.amount;

    if *bta_balance < amount {
        return err!(TokenUseError::NotEnoughBalance);
    }

    let seeds = b"nft";
    let bump = ctx.bumps.nft_mint;
    let signer: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[seeds, &[bump]]];

    
    let token_balance = & ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.amount;
    
    let mut nft_mint = (*token_balance % 10 + amount) % 10;

    // transfer nft
    while nft_mint > 0{
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        MintTo {
            mint: ctx.accounts.nft_mint.to_account_info(), // mint account of token to mint
            to: ctx.accounts.buyer_nft_account.to_account_info(), // worker token account to mint to
            authority: ctx.accounts.nft_token_account.to_account_info(), // pda is used as both address of mint and mint authority
        },
        signer
    );
    mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
    nft_mint -= 1;
    };


    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyTokens<'info>{
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        address = ADMIN_PUBKEY
    )]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"jellya"],
        bump,
    )]
    pub jelly_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"nft"],
        bump,
    )]
    pub nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = buyer,
        associated_token::mint = jelly_token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = buyer
    )]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = buyer,
        associated_token::mint = nft_mint,
        associated_token::authority = buyer
    )]
    pub buyer_nft_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = jelly_token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = admin,

    )]
    pub jelly_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = nft_mint,
        associated_token::authority = admin,
    )]
    pub nft_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

here is my test code,
const usdc_amount = new anchor.BN(3);
  it("Is buy jelly tokens!", async() => {
    const tx = await program.methods
    .buytokens(usdc_amount)
    .accounts({
      buyer: buyer.publicKey,
      admin: admin.publicKey,
      buyerTokenAccount: BuyerTokenAccount,
      buyerNftAccount: BuyerNftAccount,
      jellyTokenMint: JellyTokenMintPDA,
      nftMint: NftTokenMintPDA,
      jellyTokenAccount: JellyTokenAccount,
      nftTokenAccount: NftTokenAccount,
    })
    .signers([buyer, admin])
    .rpc({
      skipPreflight:true
    });
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  })

I deploy it on the localnet, and I serached the transaction signature, it looks like
[
  "Program HwBzMVErZCtZekzcH89JV5envYrvLFGGN7YqpeDo3GnK invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Instruction: Buytokens2",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Create",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1595 of 182403 compute units",
  "Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program log: Initialize the associated token account",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner",
  "Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 175790 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 171908 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20389 of 187800 compute units",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Create",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1595 of 148836 compute units",
  "Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program log: Initialize the associated token account",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner",
  "Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 142223 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 138341 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20389 of 154233 compute units",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Create",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1595 of 116139 compute units",
  "Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program log: Initialize the associated token account",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner",
  "Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 109526 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 105644 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 21889 of 123036 compute units",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Create",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1595 of 84942 compute units",
  "Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program log: Initialize the associated token account",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner",
  "Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 78329 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 74447 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20389 of 90339 compute units",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Create",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1595 of 55245 compute units",
  "Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program log: Initialize the associated token account",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner",
  "Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 48632 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 44750 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20389 of 60642 compute units",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success",
  "Program HwBzMVErZCtZekzcH89JV5envYrvLFGGN7YqpeDo3GnK consumed 170146 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program HwBzMVErZCtZekzcH89JV5envYrvLFGGN7YqpeDo3GnK failed: Overlapping copy"
]

anyone know how to solve it?

There's some missing info here because the code is only calling MintTo, but the logs show way more programs being called. CopyOverlapping comes from an incorrect call to find_program_address or get_return_data. Check and see where you might be using those with strange inputs
